# PHP Script Reads and Writes on Localhost but only Reads on Server

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm writing a simple script to create new rows in a database, read, and update those rows/entries. I'm connecting to a database hosted by rackspace. When I run the script on my localhost server (wamp) I can read, write, and update the database. But when I run it on the server (same exact script) it reads from the database but will not write or update the database. I've contacted Rackspace and they were no help... Here's my script. Any suggestions?

```
<?php

include_once('sanitize.php');   //sanitize.php used to sterilize inputs

/************************************************************************************/
/********************************* DATABASE CLASS ***********************************/
/************************************************************************************/

$hostname = 'xxx';
$database = 'xxx';
$username = 'xxx';
$password = 'xxx';

try {$DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);}
catch(PDOException $e) { echo $e->getMessage();}

/************************************************************************************/
/********************************* MAIN FUNCTIONS ***********************************/
/************************************************************************************/

function list_active_orders() {
    global $DBH;

    $STH = $DBH -> prepare("SELECT * FROM orders ORDER BY id DESC");
    $STH -> execute();
    $dataSet = $STH -> fetchAll();

    echo "<table class='activeOrders'>
            <tr>
                <th>DocNum</th>
                <th>Customer</th>
                <th>Rep</th>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Ordered</th>
                <th>Shipped</th>
                <th>Received</th>
                <th>Delieverd</th>
            </tr>";
    foreach ($dataSet as $data) {
        if(!$data['Ordered']) {
            $Ordered = "<input type='checkbox' name='Ordered' value='Ordered' class='orderedCheckbox'>";
        }
        else {
            $Ordered = $data['Ordered'];
        }
        if(!$data['Shipped']) {
            $Shipped = "<input type='checkbox' name='Shipped' value='Shipped' class='shippedCheckbox'>";
        }
        else {
            $Shipped = $data['Shipped'];
        }
        if(!$data['Received']) {
            $Received = "<input type='checkbox' name='Received' value='Received' class='receivedCheckbox'>";
        }
        else {
            $Received = $data['Received'];
        }
        if(!$data['Delivered']) {
            $Delivered = "<input type='checkbox' name='Delivered' value='Delivered' class='deliveredCheckbox'>";
        }
        else {
            $Delivered = $data['Delivered'];
        }
        echo "<tr id='".$data['id']."'>";
        echo "<td>".$data['DocNum']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$data['Customer']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$data['Rep']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$data['Product']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$Ordered."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$Shipped."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$Received."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$Delivered."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}

function new_order($DocNum, $Customer, $Rep, $Product) {
    global $DBH;
    $STH = $DBH -> prepare("INSERT INTO orders (DocNum, Customer, Rep, Product) VALUES (:DocNum, :Customer, :Rep, :Product)");
    $STH -> bindValue(':DocNum', $DocNum, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $STH -> bindValue(':Customer', $Customer, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $STH -> bindValue(':Rep', $Rep, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $STH -> bindValue(':Product', $Product, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $STH -> execute();
}

function update_order($column, $date, $id) {
    global $DBH;
    switch ($column) {
        case 'Ordered':
            $STH = $DBH -> prepare("UPDATE orders SET Ordered = :d WHERE id = :id");
            break;

        case 'Shipped':
            $STH = $DBH -> prepare("UPDATE orders SET Shipped = :d WHERE id = :id");
            break;

        case 'Received':
            $STH = $DBH -> prepare("UPDATE orders SET Received = :d WHERE id = :id");
            break;

        case 'Delivered':
            $STH = $DBH -> prepare("UPDATE orders SET Delivered = :d WHERE id = :id");
            break;

        default:
            # code...
            break;
    }

    $STH -> bindValue(':d', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $STH -> bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $STH -> execute();
}




/************************************************************************************/
/********************************** CONTROL LOOP ************************************/
/************************************************************************************/

$action         = sanitize(@$_POST['action']);
$DocNum         = sanitize(@$_POST['DocNum']);
$Customer       = sanitize(@$_POST['Customer']);
$Rep            = sanitize(@$_POST['Rep']);
$Product        = sanitize(@$_POST['Product']);
$column         = sanitize(@$_POST['column']);
$date           = sanitize(@$_POST['d']);
$id             = sanitize(@$_POST['id']);


switch ($action) {
    case 'view_orders':
        list_active_orders();
        break;
    case 'new_order':
        new_order($DocNum, $Customer, $Rep, $Product);
        break;
    case 'Update_Order':
        update_order($column, $date, $id);
        break;

    default:
        break;
}

?>
```

******************UPDATE**************

I found the problem... It was with my sanitize.php file. After looking at my php error logs I found this entry hundreds of times

```
[28-Apr-2014 15:54:43 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  mysql_real_escape_string() [<a href='function.mysql-real-escape-string'>function.mysql-real-escape-string</a>]: A link to the server could not be established in /mnt/target03/354651/orders.entrerock.com/web/content/sanitize.php on line 26
```

After removing the sanitize.php from my functions.php file I was able to write to the database. My question is why is this error happening? I've used this sanitize script before and never had any problems with it. Here's the script...

```
<?php
function cleanInput($input) {

  $search = array(
    '@<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>@si',   // Strip out javascript
    '@<[\/\!]*?[^<>]*?>@si',            // Strip out HTML tags
    '@<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>@siU',    // Strip style tags properly
    '@<![\s\S]*?--[ \t\n\r]*>@'         // Strip multi-line comments
  );

    $output = preg_replace($search, '', $input);
    return $output;
}

function sanitize($input) {
    if (is_array($input)) {
        foreach($input as $var=>$val) {
            $output[$var] = sanitize($val);
        }
    }
    else {
        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $input = stripslashes($input);
        }
        $input  = cleanInput($input);
        $output = mysql_real_escape_string($input);
    }
    return $output;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your mysql host/user/pass/db names... better go change those **NOW**. Plus, mysql accounts are created as user@host pairs (with wildcards allowed for either). You might have two entirely different mysql accounts based on your local + remote addresses, and you're connecting to one that only allows reads.

Comment: Their unique user and pass for a test database with no valid data but thankyou for xxxing them out. How can I be connecting to two different databases if both (server and local) scripts show the same data and when I update the database from the local script the server script shows the changes?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do that with the same connection. You have to make a new `PDO` class for the other connection, and then do the exact same thing on that :)

Comment: because mysql uses the source IP of the connection plus the username to create a user account. user@127.0.0.1 is a completely different account from user@127.0.0.2, even though they're both "user". each can have its own grants. If you grants were done as `user@%`, then it'd be wildcarded and wouldn't matter. but if wildcards weren't used, then it's possible the two accounts have different grants.

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman - I've done it before with other scripts after asking here on stackoverflow how to only declare my credentials once.

Comment: @MarcB - But why would that make one be able to write and one not be able to?

Comment: different accounts = potentially different permissions. it's entirely possible to grant `select` but not `update`.

Comment: That makes sense except I've only set up one account and I'm using the same credentials on both scripts to access the database. I get that essentially their different because they're accessing the database from different IPs but that shouldn't change the r/w permissions. And if it does't have w permissions shouldn't it throw an error at me?

Comment: See update to original question

Comment: You use `catch(PDOException $e) { echo $e->getMessage();}` but you dont ,,die'' the page so exucution goes further. Even if the connection is not established. Maybe that will tell you more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is why is this error happening?

The answer to that is that you are trying to mix two libraries, `PDO` and `mysql_*`.

In addtion to that `mysql_*` is deprecated but I believe you already know that.

I won't be able to give you the inner reasons, but it's just a bad idea to do that.

If you are using PDO, and you are preparing your query properly you should not have to worry about escaping vairables.